# How to get the average in pl/sql from a count within multiplel dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

in the following query where I make a COUNT:

```
SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS
FROM  ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO  WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-03-12'  AND IDAPLICACION = 01
GROUP BY FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
01/12/20    01    62172
02/12/20    01    61812
03/12/20    01    63032
```

How can I make this query also give me the average of the counts 62172, 61812 and 63032?
Which result should be 62338.66667 (which can be rounded if possible, I dont mind)

I try the following but I dont think its working:

```
SELECT AVG(NRO_REGISTROS) FROM (SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS
FROM  ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO  WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-02-12' AND IDAPLICACION = 01
GROUP BY FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION) GROUP BY NRO_REGISTROS;
```

I appreciate the help and sorry for 'novice' like question

Comment: `SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS, AVG(COUNT(*) * 1.0) OVER () FROM ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(NRO_REGISTROS)
FROM (SELECT FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION, COUNT(*) as NRO_REGISTROS
      FROM ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO 
      WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-03-12'  AND
            IDAPLICACION = 01
      GROUP BY FECHAGENERACION, IDAPLICACION
     ) FI;
```

Another uses `COUNT(DISTINCT)` -- but assumes that the two keys are never `NULL` and can be separated unambiguously:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT FECHAGENERACION || '|' ||  IDAPLICACION)
FROM ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO 
WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-03-12' AND
      IDAPLICACION = 01;
```

And a third method would add an additional column to the existing data set:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT FECHAGENERACION || '|' ||  IDAPLICACION),
       SUM(COUNT(*)) / COUNT(*) OVER () as overall_avg
FROM ADMBLOQMON.BOC_MAEBLOQAUX_BLOQ_MONO 
WHERE fechageneracion between DATE '2020-01-12' AND DATE '2020-03-12' AND
      IDAPLICACION = 01;
```

Comment: Thank you bro, I will try it tomorrow at work and comment here if any doubts :) which one would you say is the best method in terms of speed?

Comment: @BugsOverflow . . . The first two return a single number.  The third returns an additional column, so they do different things.  I would expect the first two to have similar performance, but it is always worth trying on your data and your system.